# Run multiple jobs at the same time using laravel queue

Tags: php, laravel, asynchronous, redis, queue

I'm trying to use laravel queuing in my project via redis driver. This is working well.
Now I want to tell laravel to process jobs as much as possible at the same time. I didn't find any related documents. Is it possible? How can I do that?

Comment: jobs are running in CLI mode ?

Comment: Yes. Currently i'm running jobs in CLI mode. They could run using http too.

Comment: take a look about this : https://sourceforge.net/projects/phpthreadlib/

Comment: Than you @IlyasMimouni but I'm trying to use laravel queue. I have been using other solutions before.

Comment: I've answered this with part of my answer to another question of yours: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37826768/is-laravel-queue-system-suitable-for-big-projects